# How to set X-axis units to datetime of empty plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, datetime, plot

I have created figure with `figure;` and didn't plot anything on it.

How can I set it's x-axis to be `datetime` from this situation?

Entering

```
xlim([startTime, endTime]);
```

causes

```
Limits must be a 2-element vector of increasing numeric values.
```

How to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Since the [xlim](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html) function accepts a vector of two numeric values (the first one being the minimum and the second one representing the maximum), you can convert your datetime values into the required numeric values by using the [datenum](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) function. For example:

```
xlim([datenum(startTime) datenum(endTime)]);
```

In order to make your x-axis readable, you can make a call to [datetick](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html) in order to convert the tick labels back to a valid datetime format. For example:

```
datetick('x','dd-mm-yyyy');
```

Here is a very basic example:

```
date_beg = datetime(2016,01,01);
date_end = datetime(2017,12,31);
date_seq = date_beg:date_end;

x = datenum(date_seq);
y = 1:numel(date_seq);

plot(x,y);
datetick('x','dd-mm-yyyy');
```

[image: Screen]

If you want to preserve the x-axis limits, call the `datetick` function passing the `keeplimits` argument. Here is a code snippet that reproduces your attempt:

```
date_beg = datetime(2016,01,01);
date_end = datetime(2017,09,15);

figure();
xlim([datenum(date_beg) datenum(date_end)]);
datetick('x','dd-mm-yyyy','keeplimits');
```

Comment: The solution here only "fakes" a datetime axes, but XAxis is still a NumericRuler. DatetimeRulers controls much more than just labels.